# TradingView - Pine Script Help. One Trade Per Condition

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way / command to set that a condition must be met before entering a trade i.e. only go long when close(1)BBlow and highest(20) > stoch 80. I only want 1 trade when the price was above stoch 80 and then followed by close < BBlow etc. I dont want multiple trades every time the close(1) < BBlow and close>BBlow. Only 1 trade per entire condition. Hope this makes sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[4 Trades but only want 2. 1 per condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZiUu.png)

In the picture, I only want two trades and not 4. Setting pyramiding to 1 also doesn't help as I want 1 trade per condition and not just 1 trade.

Comment: Update:https://getsatisfaction.com/tradingview/topics/enter-trade-only-once-per-condition

Answer (score 1):

As the reply, from the other thread you linked too, points out, the condition you are using can be true in subsequent periods, even though a position has already been open. Perhaps you could utilize the *[crossover](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_crossover)* or *[crossunder](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_crossunder)* functions to isolate the event when one value crosses over/under another instead of checking if one value is larger/smaller than another. This would return false in subsequent periods as crossover/under has not occurred, but close is still greater than, or less than, the value in question.

Hope this helps